# Why is there an error in generics when sorting an array?

Tags: java

You need to write an array sort. But there is an error "Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'T', 'T'" and "Incompatible types. Found: 'T[]', required: 'T'". What is the problem, why is it?

```
public class MySortArray <T extends Comparable <T>>{

    public T SortArray(T[] array) {
        int temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {

            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading).

You must use the [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
if (array[i].compareTo(array[i+1]) > 0)
```